# Getting error Failed to load image while working with android vision api for scanning qr code

Tags: java, android, qr-code, barcode-scanner, vision-api

I am using the following code to scan the QR code and show it.

Main Activity

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_bg1);


        scan =(Button) findViewById(R.id.scanner);



        scan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                boolean isGooglePlayUpdated=isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(BG1.this);

                if (isGooglePlayUpdated){
                     ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(BG1.this, new
                        String[]{android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUEST_WRITE_PERMISSION);
                }
                else
                    Toast.makeText(BG1.this,"Please update Google Play Services",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

}

     @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_WRITE_PERMISSION:
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    takePicture();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(BG1.this, "Permission Denied!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }


        }
    }


    private void takePicture() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(BG1.this,scanActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, PHOTO_REQUEST);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

                            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == PHOTO_REQUEST) {

            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){

                if (data!=null){
                    String qrCode = data.getParcelableExtra(scanActivity.BarcodeObject);
                    Toast.makeText(BG1.this,qrCode,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Log.d(TAG, "Barcode read: " + qrCode);
                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(BG1.this,"intent data is null",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Log.d(TAG, "No barcode captured, intent data is null");
                }
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(BG1.this,"Result code error ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.d(TAG, "Result code error");
            }
        }
        else {
    }

}
```

scanActivity.java

```
public class scanActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static String TAG="scan Activity";
    SurfaceView cameraView;
    BarcodeDetector barcodeDetector;
    CameraSource cameraSource;
    SurfaceHolder holder;
    public static final String BarcodeObject = "Barcode";



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.scan_activity);

        cameraView=(SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.camera_view);
        cameraView.setZOrderMediaOverlay(true);
        holder=cameraView.getHolder();

        barcodeDetector=new BarcodeDetector.Builder(this)
                .setBarcodeFormats(Barcode.QR_CODE)
                .build();

        if (!barcodeDetector.isOperational()){

            Toast.makeText(this,"Sorry Can't setup",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            // Check for low storage.  If there is low storage, the native library will not be
            // downloaded, so detection will not become operational.
            IntentFilter lowstorageFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_DEVICE_STORAGE_LOW);
            boolean hasLowStorage = registerReceiver(null, lowstorageFilter) != null;

            if (hasLowStorage) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Low Storage", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.w(TAG, "Low Storage");
            }

            this.finish();
        }

        try {
            cameraSource.release();

        }catch (NullPointerException e){
            Log.e("Camera Realease", "Yes");
            Toast.makeText(scanActivity.this,"Camerea Release ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        cameraSource=new CameraSource.Builder(this,barcodeDetector)
                .setFacing(CameraSource.CAMERA_FACING_BACK)
                .setRequestedFps(24)
                .setAutoFocusEnabled(true)
                .setRequestedPreviewSize(1920,1024)
                .build();


        cameraView.getHolder().addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {

                try
                {
                    cameraSource.start(cameraView.getHolder());
                }catch (Exception i){
                    Log.e("cameraSource start()", "Yes");
                    i.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(scanActivity.this,"Error while opening the camera",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {

            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {

            cameraSource.stop();

            }
        });


        barcodeDetector.setProcessor(new Detector.Processor<Barcode>() {
            @Override
            public void release() {

            }

            @Override
            public void receiveDetections(Detector.Detections<Barcode> detections) {

                SparseArray<Barcode> barcodes = detections.getDetectedItems();


                if (barcodes.size()>0){

                    System.out.println("Barcode "+barcodes.valueAt(0).displayValue);
                    //Toast.makeText(scanActivity.this,barcodes.valueAt(0).toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    Intent intent=new Intent();
                    //storing into global variable
                    Constants.qrCode=barcodes.valueAt(0).displayValue;
                    intent.putExtra(BarcodeObject,barcodes.valueAt(0).displayValue);
//                  //stop the camera

                    setResult(RESULT_OK,intent);
                    finish();
                }



            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        cameraSource=null;
    }
}
```

So I am facing the following error:

I am getting the scanned QR code in the scan activity but the onActivityResult() method in mainActivity.java is not getting called.

Comment: your takePicture() method is being called

Comment: yes, it is calling but in the scanActivity.java setResult() method is not calling.@DkThakur